# C# - Print out a key and its value in a dictionary depending on a users input?

Tags: c#, dictionary, input, output

me again :D

This is my current code:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Declare all numbers
            int electronNumber;
            int protonNumber;
            float neutronNumber;
            int i;
            int indexOfElementName;
            int restartInt;
            restartInt = 1;

            // Declare all strings
            string elementRequest;
            string restartString;

            var elementDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
            { "Hydrogen", "H" },
            { "Helium", "He" },
            { "Lithium", "Li" },
            { "Beryllium", "Be" },
            { "Boron", "B" },
            { "Carbon", "C" },
            { "Nitrogen", "N" },
            { "Oxygen", "O" },
            { "Fluroine", "F" },
            { "Neon", "Ne" },
            { "Sodium", "Na" },
            { "Magnesium", "Mg" },
            { "Aluminium", "Al" },
            { "Silicon", "Si" },
            { "Phosphorus", "P" },
            { "Sulfur", "S" },
            { "Chlorine", "Cl" },
            { "Argon", "Ar" },
            { "Potassium", "K" },
            { "Calcium", "Ca" },
            { "Scandium", "Sc" },
            { "Titanium", "Ti" },
            { "Vanadium", "V" },
            { "Chromium", "Cr" },
            { "Manganese", "Mn" },
            { "Iron", "Fe" },
            { "Cobalt", "Co" },
            { "Nickel", "Ni" },
            { "Copper", "Cu" },
            { "Zinc", "Zn" },
            { "Gallium", "Ga" },
            { "Germanium", "Ge" },
            { "Arsenic", "As" },
            { "Selenium", "Se" },
            { "Bromine", "Br" },
            { "Krypton", "Kr" },
            { "Rubidium", "Rb" },
            { "Strontium", "Sr" },
            { "Yttrium", "Y" },
            { "Zirconium", "Zr" },
            { "Niobium", "Nb" },
            { "Molybdenum", "Mo" },
            { "Technetium", "Tc" },
            { "Ruhenium", "Ru" },
            { "Palladium", "Pd" },
            { "Silver", "Ag" },
            { "Cadmium", "Cd" },
            { "Indium", "In" },
            { "Tin", "Sn" },
            { "Antimony", "Sb" },
            { "Tellurium", "Te" },
            { "Iodine", "I" },
            { "Xenon", "Xe" },
            { "Caesium", "Cs" },
            { "Barium", "Ba" },
            { "Lanthanum", "La" },
            { "Cerium", "Ce" },
            { "Praesodynium", "Pr" },
            { "Neodynium", "Nd" },
            { "Promethium", "Pm" },
            { "Samarium", "Sm" },
            { "Europium", "Eu" },
            { "Gadolinium", "Gd" },
            { "Terbium", "Tb" },
            { "Dysprosium", "Dy" },
            { "Holmium", "Ho" },
            { "Erbium", "Er" },
            { "Thulium", "Tm" },
            { "Ytterbium", "Yb" },
            { "Lutetium", "Lu" },
            { "Hafnium", "Hf" },
            { "Tantalum", "Ta" },
            { "Tungsten", "W" },
            { "Rhenium", "Re" },
            { "Osmium", "Os" },
            { "Iridium", "Ir" },
            { "Platinum", "Pt" },
            { "Gold", "Au" },
            { "Mercury", "Hg" },
            { "Thallium", "Tl" },
            { "Lead", "Pb" },
            { "Bismuth", "Bi" },
            { "Polonium", "Po" },
            { "Astatine", "At" },
            { "Radon", "Rn" },
            { "Francium", "Fr" },
            { "Radium", "Ra" },
            { "Actinium", "Ac" },
            { "Thorium", "Th" },
            { "Protactinium", "Pa" },
            { "Uranium", "U" },
            { "Neptunium", "Np" },
            { "Plutonium", "Pu" },
            { "Americium", "Am" },
            { "Curium", "Cm" },
            { "Berkelium", "Bk" },
            { "Californium", "Cf" },
            { "Einsteinium", "Es" },
            { "Fermium", "Fm" },
            { "Mendelevium", "Md" },
            { "Nobelium", "No" },
            { "Lawrencium", "Lr" },
            { "Rutherfordium", "Rf" },
            { "Dubnium", "Db" },
            { "Seaborgium", "Sg" },
            { "Bohrium", "Bh" },
            { "Hassium", "Hs" },
            { "Meitnerium", "Mt" },
            { "Darmstadtium", "Ds" },
            { "Roentgenium", "Rg" },
            { "Copernicium", "Cn" },

            };
                while (restartInt == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What element do you want? Either input it's full name, with a capital letter. E.g 'Hydrogen'");
                elementRequest = Console.ReadLine();
                string elementSymbol = elementDictionary[elementRequest];
                Console.WriteLine("Your element: " + elementRequest + " has the element symbol of: " + elementSymbol);

                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? Type '1' for yes, and '2' for no.");
                restartString = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(restartString, out restartInt);


            };
        }
    }
```

As the dictionary list is in order of the elements respective atomic number, how can I count from the start to the inputted element so that I can find the elements atomic number. Also, how do can I simply print out both the element name and its symbol?

For example:

elementRequest = "Nitrogen" should print out:

Element Name - "Nitrogen"
Element Symbol - "N"
Element's atomic number = 7

I tried to do a loop to add 1 for each addition into the dictionary, but it kept outputting the atomic number as the total number of items in the dictionary.

For the printing of both the name and the symbol, ("Nitrogen", "N"), another fantastic helper on here told me how to get the symbol, but the line:

```
string elementSymbol = elementDictionary[elementRequest];
```

only prints out its symbol, not its element name and its symbol, and I'm not entirely sure why or how to fix it. Surely by putting [elementRequest] in should find both the "Hydrogen" and "H"? or am I misunderstanding something?

Any help is appreciated! :D

Comment: Can you show the loop you tried so far?

Comment: If you want to save element's order, you should use a List<KeyParValue<string,string>>, because dictionary does not guarantee order.

Comment: I deleted it as it didn't work. Now that I think about it though, could I add a third section to the dictionary for the atomic number as the number doesn't change and then just print all 3 parts of it? That would also make  idea obsolete as the order wouldn't matter since the number would be stored with its atomic name.

@ltiveron would that replace the line     var elementDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try a class to represent the element.

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set;}
    public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }

    public Element(string name, string symbol, int atomicNumber)
    {
        Name = name;
        Symbol = symbol;
        AtomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    }
}
```

Add to the dictionary like this:

```
var elementDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Element>
{
        { "Hydrogen", new Element("Hydrogen", "H", 1) },
        { "Helium", new Element("Helium", "He", 2) },

        //etc.
};
```

then when you lookup in the dictionary, you get the class so can access all its properties

```
elementRequest = Console.ReadLine();
var element = elementDictionary[elementRequest];
Console.WriteLine("Your element: " + element.Name + " has the element symbol of: " + element.Symbol + " and atomic number of: " + element.AtomicNumber);
```

You can then add further properties to your element class and have them all available when you retreive from the dictionary

**EDIT - COMPLETE CODE TESTED AND WORKING**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int restartInt;
            restartInt = 1;

            // Declare all strings
            string elementRequest;
            string restartString;

            var elementDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Element>
            {
                { "Hydrogen", new Element("Hydrogen", "H", 1) },
                { "Helium", new Element("Helium", "He", 2) },

                //etc.
            };

            while (restartInt == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What element do you want? Either input it's full name, with a capital letter. E.g 'Hydrogen'");

                elementRequest = Console.ReadLine();
                var element = elementDictionary[elementRequest];
                Console.WriteLine("Your element: " + element.Name + " has the element symbol of: " + element.Symbol + " and atomic number of: " + element.AtomicNumber);

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? Type '1' for yes, and '2' for no.");
                restartString = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(restartString, out restartInt);
            };
        }
    }


    public class Element
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }

        public Element(string name, string symbol, int atomicNumber)
        {
            Name = name;
            Symbol = symbol;
            AtomicNumber = atomicNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Do you know of anymore info on classes? I wanna read up on them!

Comment: its a fundamental principle if you're going to write c# code - just google "c# class" and you will find lots of information!

Comment: Using this code, I get an error for var which states "the contextual keyword "var" may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code. Where should I move it to? Perhaps inside the brackets of the public class?

Comment: The code runs fine, I'm not sure why you have that error

Comment: oh I see - you should put the second two paragraphs of code where your original code was - ie inside your static void Main method. The first paragraph of code (the Element class) should go after your Program class.

Comment: That gives another error since the element.Name, element.Symbol, element.AtomicNumber are do not have a definition, so it causes a new error. Perhaps I could call it?